# Reinsert delimiters after using awk and sort

Tags: shell, sorting, awk

I'm very new to scripting so forgive me if this is a ridiculously obvious question. I'm writing a appointment tracking script in Bourne shell (have to use Bourne unfortunately). I need to sort the appointments in date order with each appointment comprised of 7 columns separated by colons as such:

> 1:26:2013:Saturday:16.00:17.30:Barbecue
>   1:24:2013:Thursday:14.00:15.10:CSS Meeting
>   1:25:2013:Friday:12.00:12.30:Business Lunch
>   1:27:2013:Sunday:10.00:17.30:Volunteer beach cleanup
>   2:24:2013:Sunday:20.00:24.00:Party
>   2:11:2013:Monday:16.00:17.30:Dentist visit
>   1:24:2013:Thursday:11.00:11.45:Project meeting
>   3:24:2013:Sunday:8.00:11.30:Church picnic
>   2:8:2013:Friday:12.00:17.30:Halo tournament
>   1:19:2013:Saturday:16.00:20.30:Poker

here's what I have so far which does exactly what I want except it takes out my colon delimiters. `awk -F : '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 |"sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n -k3,3n -n -o appts.txt"}' appts.txt`

> 1 19 2013 Saturday 16.00 20.30 Poker
>   1 24 2013 Thursday 11.00 11.45 Project meeting
>   1 24 2013 Thursday 14.00 15.10 CSS Meeting
>   1 25 2013 Friday 12.00 12.30 Business Lunch
>   1 26 2013 Saturday 16.00 17.30 Barbecue

How do I get my colon delimiters back?

Comment: Shouldn't the sort order be `-k 3n -k 1n -k 2n` or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is, don't remove them in the first place.  At least with my version of sort, it works as expected with the original file:

```
sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n -k3,3n -n -o appts2.txt < appts.txt
```

Though, it does also support explicitly specifying a field separator (`-t`). So to be safe, you can say:

```
sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n -k3,3n -n -t: -o appts2.txt < appts.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm ridiculous... not sure why I used awk in the first place.

This did what I wanted just fine

```
sort -k 1,1 -k 2,2n -k3,3n -n -t: -o appts.txt appts.txt
```